# do i need to traverse both subtrees for computing, the root to leaf sum, to a given value?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree

This is the problem statement:

"Given a tree and a sum, return true if there is a path from the root 
 down to a leaf, such that adding up all the values along the path 
 equals the given sum."

I implemented it like this:

```
int hasPathSum(Node* node, int sum) {
    if(node == NULL)
        return sum == 0;

    int diff = sum - node->data;

    if(diff < 0) return 0;

    if(diff == 0)
        return node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL ? 1 : 0;

    if(diff < node->data)
        return hasPathSum(node->left, diff);
    else
        return hasPathSum(node->right, diff);
}
```

I only traverse 1 sub-tree and not both, depending on the difference of `(sum - node->data)`.

However, the recommended solution required traversing both the subtrees like this:

```
int hasPathSum(Node* node, int sum) { 
  // return true if we run out of tree and sum==0 
  if (node == NULL) { 
    return(sum == 0); 
  } 
  else { 
  // otherwise check both subtrees 
    int subSum = sum - node->data; 
    return(hasPathSum(node->left, subSum) || 
           hasPathSum(node->right, subSum)); 
  } 
}
```

I don't see why do we have to traverse both the subtrees ?

Here is the source of the problem: [Problem 7](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)

**EDIT**:

Bad assumption on my part that the tree is a BST. Its just a binary tree.

However, if it were a BST, I'd like to hear some feedback on my implementation ? Would it not be better to do it the way I did it than the other solution ? (which is a little unfair to compare since that solution is for *any* binary tree)

**EDIT** *solution*:

Please see anatolyg's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11959031/280924) which explains the problem with my proposed solution. Thanks anatolyg.

Comment: This is not homework. I'm just doing it as a personal exercise, brushing up on tree exercises :)

Comment: So your tree is upside down....Please share with me as well,I'd like to have it in my garden. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement doesn't mention anything about how the tree is arranged, so I don't appreciate what your left/right test is trying to do.  You can't know anything about the contents of the `node->left` or `node->right` subtrees without testing them.

Also, in the suggested solution the `||` is going to short-circuit if the left subtree matches, so you are not necessarily traversing both subtrees.  You only traverse the entire tree if there is no path:  you obviously have to test every path to be sure there isn't one.  (Ok, you also traverse the entire tree if you find a match on the final path...)

Comment: In the link (not in the question), the trees are defined as binary search trees

Comment: Aha! Yes, I had been solving all the previous problems and they were binary search trees. I conveniently assumed this tree to be a BST as well ! My bad.

Comment: @Ben What do you think of my solution if it was a BST ??

Comment: @brainydexter: I don't see an optimization for binary trees offhand.  Perhaps something more like a heap would have a clever solution.

Comment: @BenJackson Now you've made me curios :). How would a heap help ?

Comment: @brainydexter: A max heap would quickly eliminate subtrees that were greater than the target sum.  If the target sum was actually larger than all paths you'd still end up with a full search.

Comment: In a max heap, only root is the greatest element of all the elements. This property is not recursive. How would this then `eliminate subtrees that were greater than the target sum` ?

Answer (score 2):

The special arrangement of the nodes in the binary search tree only helps in searching for a number, not for a sum. Imagine a very big tree, with depth of like 100, having the sought-for path along all the left nodes, and the target sum moderately big (e.g. 1+2+3+...+100).

When your algorithm starts from the root, the `diff` will be large, and it will go to the right branch of the tree, where the sum doesn't necessarily exist (e.g. all elements there are greater than 1000000000, so too big).

Comment: Is this pertinent to BST or the solution I proposed ? (I wrote the solution thinking it was a BST)

Comment: Ah. I see. Even though the left node may be smaller than the difference, but the sum of nodes in left subtree might be equal to the sum and hence, left subtree should not be ignored. Also, I get your point about using BST for searching and not for activities like finding sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a binary tree with root node with data 1. The root node has two subtrees, the left holds 2, and the right holds 3. The node 2 has a left subtree of 5.

If you ask if a path from the overall root to a leaf node can add up to a sum of 8, the answer is yes.

overall root = 1, left subtree = 2, left subtree = 5, which adds up to 8. However, you don't know ahead of time which path will add up to the correct sum if any, so you must go down both subtrees recursively.

Binary tree code should be short. Use the recursive nature of binary trees and the fact that a tree is either null or it has left and right subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

the tree isn't a [search tree](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/binarySearchTree.htm) and there for, you don't know any thing about the child’s  data from the fathers data.